# Probability density function $\max\{2,X\}$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with a PDF $f(x)=\frac{1}{9}x^2\mathbb{1}_{(0,3)}(x)$. Find the distribution and PDF of $Y=\max\{2,X\}$ .

$F_X(t)=\int\limits_0^tf(x)dx=\int\limits_0^t\frac{1}{9}x^2dx=\frac{t^3}{27}$

$Y=\begin{cases}
                    2 &\text{for $X \in (0,2)$} \\
                    X &\text{for $X \in [2,3)$}
\end{cases}$

$F_Y(t)=\Bbb P(Y \leq t)=\Bbb P(\max\{2,X\}\leq t)=\Bbb P(2\leq t, X\leq t)= \ ?$

PDF:

$f_Y(t)=\begin{cases}
                    C &\text{for $X \in (0,2)$} \\
                    \frac{1}{9}x^2 &\text{for $X \in [2,3)$}
\end{cases}$

$\int\limits_0^2Cdt+\int\limits_2^3\frac{1}{9}t^2dt=2C+\frac{19}{27}=1$, then:
$C=\frac{4}{27}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that Y-support is the following: $y \in[2;3]$

Then observe that $P(Y=2)=F_X(2)=\int_0^2 f(x)dx=\frac{8}{27}$

Concluding, Y-distribution is the following

$$ F_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $y<2$} \\
\frac{8}{27},  & \text{if $y=2$} \\
\frac{y^3}{27},  & \text{if $2<y<3$} \\
1,  & \text{if $y\geq 3$}
\end{cases}$$

As you can see the distribution function has "a jump" in $Y=2$ thus the rv is not absolutely continuous (it is a mixed distribution)

So technically the PDF (as it is defined only for continuous rv) does not exist.

Actually there is a generalization of density called "mixed density", or "mixed PDF". You can calculate it by derivating F where the variable is continuous and calculating $p(y_0)=F_Y(y_0^+)-F_Y(y_0^-)$ where Y is discrete (in your case in $Y=2$)

---

Here is a drawing of the transformation function. The line in red is $Y=max(2;X)$

[image]

As you can see, when $X \in (0;2]$, a mass of probability $p=\frac{8}{27}$ is concentrated in a singleton: $Y=2$. This means that the resulting Law of Y is discret in this point...in the rest of Y-support, Y is continuous being $Y=X$

Comment: thanks! but why can't I just write $\frac{y^3}{27}$ for $y \in [2,3)$?

Comment: @itsme: of course you can. I just wanted to underline that the distribution is mixed and in $Y=2$ it is discrete

Comment: thanks again. But I don't think I completely see that the distribution is mixed. In $Y=2$ there is a peak indeed, but $Y \in [2,3)$ and inside of this interval $F_Y(y)$ is differentiable, isn't it?

Comment: @itsme: F is discontinuous

Comment: @itsme : I edited my answer with further details to explain you why Y law is mixed. Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Answer (score 2):

The pdf is correct and you can find the CDF as well by integrating the pdf, but if you wish to find $\Pr\{\max(X,2)\le t\}$ **directly**, I suggest you the following way:
$$
\Pr\{\max(X,2)\le t\}{=
\Pr\{\max(X,2)\le t|X<2\}\Pr\{X<2\}\\+
\Pr\{\max(X,2)\le t|X\ge 2\}\Pr\{X\ge 2\}
}
$$