# Density of $\max(X, 1.5)$ for given pdf

Tags: probability

Assume that that $X$ has pdf
$$
g(x) = \frac{3}{2}\cdot x^{-2}
$$
for $x \in (1,3)$. How to compute the pdf of $Y = \max(X, 1.5)$?

Obviously
\begin{align}
\max(X, 1.5) = 
\begin{cases} 
X & \text{for}&  X \in (1.5, 3) \\ 
1.5 & \text{for}& X \in (1, 1.5] 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
F_Y(t) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq t) &= \mathbb{P}(\max(X, 1.5) \leq t) \\ &= \mathbb{P}(X \leq t, X \in (1.5, 3)) + \mathbb{P}(1.5 \leq t, X \in (1, 1.5])
\end{align}
However, I am stuck here. I guess the pdf of the first part would be simply $g(x)$ with support $(1.5,3)$ and the second density would be... $0$?

Comment: @user170231 $(1,3)$, my bad.

Comment: No worries! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909504/probability-density-function-max-2-x is a very similar exercise.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you so much!

Comment: Y has positive probability of being $1.5$ so a density may not fully descriptive